# Draw the lines detected by cv::HoughLines

Tags: c++, opencv

On this site([tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)), it show us how to draw the lines detected by cv::HoughLines,but I can't understand how could it find out the Point between the lines.

```
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
  {
     float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
     Point pt1, pt2;
     double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
     double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
     pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b)); //??
     pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a)); //??
     pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b)); //??
     pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a)); //??
     line( cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
  }
```

Example from the openCV cookbook, I could understand the reason these codes
but it is more verbose

```
for(auto const &data : lines){
    float const rho = data[0];
    float const theta = data[1];

    if((theta < PI/4. || theta > 3. * PI/4.)){
        cv::Point pt1(rho / std::cos(theta), 0);
        cv::Point pt2( (rho - result.rows * std::sin(theta))/std::cos(theta), result.rows);
        cv::line(result, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(255), 1);
    }else if{
        cv::Point pt1(0, rho / std::sin(theta));
        cv::Point pt2(result.cols, (rho - result.cols * std::cos(theta))/std::sin(theta));
        cv::line(result, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(255), 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read about [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) in opencv doc?

Comment: Yes, I can understand the examples of openCV cookbook, but can't understand the examples of the opencv doc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hough Line transform returns Polar coordinates. To display the lines on 2D picture, coordinates have to be converted do Cartesian coordinates. Here is some more info about this: http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html

Lines, returned from Hough Transform have only one Cartesian point (intersect between blue and red line):

[image]

So to display the line author converts the coordinates to Cartesian and then calculates start and end points which are set to fixed position -1000 and +1000 pixels from the converted point:

```
pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b)); //??
pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a)); //??
pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b)); //??
pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a)); //??
```

One option to find intersection between returned lines is to use this [equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection):
[image: Line-line intersection]

For more information about implementation of this see <strike>[this tutorial.](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/)</strike>