# unable to draw a line correctly using hough transformation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, hough-transform

I used [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Example:Hough_transform/MATLAB)  code for drawing lines using `Hough` tranform. In this code, there is a draw of the image in `Polar` space . I want to draw detected lines in `Cartesian` space. Thus, with the help of [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951713/draw-the-lines-detected-by-cvhoughlines) I wrote my code like this:

```
imBinary = flipud(edge(rgb2gray(im),'sobel'));
[imWidth,imLenght]=size(imBinary);
[interestPointY , interestPointX] = find(imBinary);
numberOfInterestingPoints=numel(interestPointX);
maxRadius=sqrt(imWidth^2 + imLenght^2);
polarRadius=(-maxRadius:1:maxRadius);
polarTheta=(-pi/2:(1/200):pi/2);
numberOfPolarThetas=numel(polarTheta);
houghMatrix=zeros(numel(polarRadius),numberOfPolarThetas);
polarAccumulator = zeros(numberOfInterestingPoints,numberOfPolarThetas);
cosine = (0:imWidth-1)'*cos(polarTheta);
sine = (0:imLenght-1)'*sin(polarTheta);
polarAccumulator((1:numberOfInterestingPoints),:) =cosine(interestPointY,:) + sine(interestPointX,:);
for i = (1:numberOfPolarThetas)
    houghMatrix(:,i) = hist(polarAccumulator(:,i),polarRadius);
end
radiusDetect=[];angleDetect=[];
houghBinaryMax = imregionalmax(houghMatrix);
[Potential_radius ,Potential_angle] = find(houghBinaryMax == 1);
%[radiusIndex angleIndex] = find(houghMatrix > 0);
houghTmp= houghMatrix - lineThreshold;
for cnt = 1:numel(Potential_radius)
    if houghTmp(Potential_radius(cnt),Potential_angle(cnt)) >= 0
        radiusDetect = [radiusDetect;Potential_radius(cnt)];
        angleDetect = [angleDetect;Potential_angle(cnt)];
    end
end
radius=polarRadius(radiusDetect);
deg=polarTheta(angleDetect);
%find two points in cartesian space
x=radius.*cos(deg);
y=radius.*sin(deg);
x1=x+5.*cos(deg);
y1=y+5.*cos(deg);
imshow(imBinary);
hold on;
plot([x x1],[y y1]);
```

Unfortunately I did not get the correct lines and my image in like this:[the blue lines are detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgDMi.png)

My question is what the mistake is that I cannot draw lines correctly?

Comment: I suggest providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody is going to read your huge junk of of code.

Comment: @flawr thanks for calling my code the junk :) . it is as same as the code in the link which has been used for hough transform frequentely!

Comment: Forgive me, I actually wanted to write *chunk*. Note that there actually is a [built-in](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html)